# onmouseover and hyperlink hover

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onmouseover

I had a div with links that underlined once you hover over them. I added an `onmouseover` JS event to the div and now the hyperlinks no longer underline when I hover over them, but instead whatever action I put into the `onmouseover` event gets executed instead.

**CODE from function:**

```
function addPlus(elementId)
{
 if(typeof addPlus.backup == 'undefined')
  addPlus.backup = document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML;
 if(full)
 {
  document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = plusCode + addPlus.backup;
  return backup;
 }
 else
  return snippet;
}
```

div code:

```
<div class="nav_bar" id="navbar1" onmouseover="addPlus('navbar1')" onmouseout="removePlus('navbar1')">
```

**EDIT**: I've tried `return true;`, `return Boolean(true);`, and `return new Boolean(true);`, in an attempt to "return true" as Chad suggested. None of them work. Sorry, I really don't know what to do; I'm new to Javascript.

**EDIT 2**: Darn it, I just realized Chad meant that I return true in the div tag. So now I have `<div class="nav_bar" id="navbar1" onmouseover="addPlus('navbar1');return true" onmouseout="removePlus('navbar1')">`, but it unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you doing your underline with a:hover css?

Comment: @wajiw yup, don't worry about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want for js event to fire you should stop event propogation when mouse enters `<a>`. Try adding onmouseover event handler for each hyperlink with return false - `<a onmouseover="return false" ...` - that should help.

Comment: Isn't that the exact opposite of what chad suggested? It unfortunately still does not work :( I have `<div class="nav_bar" id="navbar1" onmouseover="addPlus('navbar1');return false" onmouseout="removePlus('navbar1')">`

Comment: No, I suggested adding `return false` to links not  `<div>`. You shouldn't have `return` on `<div>` at all.

Comment: oh! I'm sorry for my confusion; however, it seems like it still does not work :(

Comment: @wrongusername - if understood better what is desired effect I would be able to find better solution, but for now please check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/grassator/9NsVJ/3/

Answer (score 0):

for the event to propagate you need to return true from your onmouseover handler.

Comment: How would I do this? `return true;`?

Answer (score 0):

1. This won't occur if you use CSS to underline your links instead of JavaScript
2. You presumably have some rotten code that is explicitly setting an `onmouseover` handler in HTML or JavaScript to handle the link underline (instead of properly using `addEventListener`), and then you are overwriting this handler. It's hard to guess what might be wrong without more information. Supply a code example for more help.

Comment: Yes, I do have an `onmouseover`, but it's not for the underline. I've posted some code